# no se genera la descarga de una ruta almacenada en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas noches compañeros, estoy tratando de descargar un archivo que esta en pdf y la ruta esta almacenada en una base de datos.
Realmente en este tema soy bastante nueva(descarga y subida de archivo), asi que lo que hize fue utilizar un enlace  donde coloco el valor de la ruta y el nombre que le quiero asignar con la herramienta de donwload que nos ofrece html.
Todo esto lo hago con PHP.
Ahora bien si bien no me lo descarga lo que hace es enviarme al pdf que deseo descargar.
Cual es la macana que me estoy mandando?
Agradezco desde ya la ayuda `

```
<?php   

                $query=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT l.idLibros,l.nombreLibro,l.descripcion,l.contenido,l.imagen,l.nombreApellido,l.estado,g.tipo 
                                                FROM libros l
                                                INNER JOIN generolibros g
                                                ON l.idGeneroLibros=g.idGeneroLibros
                                                WHERE l.estado=1 AND l.idLibros='$idLibro'");
                $consulta=mysqli_num_rows($query);

                while($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            ?>
    <form action="" method="POST" name="descargarArchivo">      
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $idLibro;?>">

    <div class="my-3">
        <div class="col-4 mx-auto">
          <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="card-header"><h4><?php echo $datos['nombreLibro'];?></h4></div>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=$datos['imagen'];?>" width="300%" height="400px" style="block-center"alt="">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p><u><h3><?php echo $datos['nombreApellido'];?></h3></u></P>
                <p><?php echo $datos['descripcion'];?></P>

                <div class="card-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" href="<?php echo $datos['contenido'];?>" donwload="<?php echo $datos['nombreLibro'];?>" name="Descargar">Descargar</a>
            </div>
            <?php }
                    
            ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

buenas noches, por lo que logre entender de tu pregunta es que deseas que el elemento  que contiene la ruta con acceso al directorio y archivo del pdf fuerce la descarga del archivo mismo, y no su visualización como hace por defecto el navegador.

Bueno, para hacer eso solo basta con agregar el atributo download al final del elemento  en cuestion esta seria la forma correcta de hacerlo:

```
<a class="btn" href="<?php echo $datos['contenido'];?>" donwload="<?php echo $datos['nombreLibro'];?>" name="Descargar" download>Descargar</a>
```

Solo hay que recordar que en el caso de chrome para que este atributo funcione el archivo en cuestión debe de ser orígen propio y no cruzado (deben estar alojados en el mismo dominio).

Cualquier pregunta que tengas no dudes en hacerla en los comentarios.

Comment: sii fuciono!!!! mil gracias, te hago una consulta si deseo que el nombre de la descarga sea el que se coloca aca **<?php echo $datos['nombreLibro'];?>** ,porque no lo hace? o es porque lo coloque mal?

Comment: @claulia ¿Qué nombre te aparece exactamente? Si deseas que te ayude más con eso necesito que me des más información respecto a tu código y el nombre que te aparece al momento de que se descarga el archivo. En resumidas cuentas lo que puedes hacer es concatenar la variable de datos con el enlace que se obtiene de descarga así obtendrías el nombre del archivo por método GET. Pero como te comento abría que estudiar más a fondo tu código si lo deseas puedo compartirte mi correo para que te ayude.

Comment: si no hay problema! también te comento por acá, que lo que hace es descargar el archivo pero con el nombre que tiene asignado en la ruta llamada contenido. Y esta encriptada,